# Matlab gets the bounding box wrong when printing an image as an eps file. How do I fix this?

Tags: matlab, latex, bounding-box, eps

Many journals require that all images appear in eps format. Matlab's imwrite function does not support eps output.  However, if you display an image in a Matlab figure using the command `imshow(myImg)`, then you can create an eps image with the command `print(gcf,'myImage.eps','-depsc')`

UNFORTUNATELY, the resulting eps image may have an incorrect bounding box (due to a Matlab bug), which can cause the image to be displayed incorrectly in a latex document.  In particular, some text in the latex document can be covered up by the eps image, because the bounding box for the eps image is too small.

Question: How do I fix this?

Note: I will provide the answer I have found, but I would also be interested in hearing any other answers or comments.

I experienced this Matlab bug with Matlab version R2015a.  This is one of those weird problems that I could never have fixed without some hard googling, and I want to make it easier for anyone in the future to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by replacing the print command in the question with:

```
set(gcf,'paperpositionmode','auto')
print(gcf,'-depsc2','-loose','myImage.eps');
```

(I found this answer [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/159509-eps-export-problems-in-r2014b).  Thanks to user CHJY on the Matlab answers forums.)

Another option is just to use a different program to convert images to eps format.